# Grails Spring Security Login Form In Another Controller

Tags: spring, security, grails, view, controller

I want to place the Login Form of the generated Login View from the Grails Spring Security Plugin at the main layout in layouts/main.gsp. I just copied it over, but it doesn't work, because of cause, now no controller is available to pass the form data to. The form-code looks like this:

```
<form action='${postUrl}' method='POST' id='loginForm' class='cssform' autocomplete='off'>
      <p>
        <label for='username'><g:message code="springSecurity.login.username.label"/>:</label>
        <input type='text' class='text_' name='j_username' id='username'/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for='password'><g:message code="springSecurity.login.password.label"/>:</label>
        <input type='password' class='text_' name='j_password' id='password'/>
      </p>
      <p id="remember_me_holder">
        <input type='checkbox' class='chk' name='${rememberMeParameter}' id='remember_me' <g:if test='${hasCookie}'>checked='checked'</g:if>/>
        <label for='remember_me'><g:message code="springSecurity.login.remember.me.label"/></label>
      </p>
      <p><input type='submit' id="submit" value='${message(code: "springSecurity.login.button")}'/></p>
    </form>
```

How should I change this code, so that I send the form code to the Login auth action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As I udenrstand, your question is what to use for form action? `postUrl` should be same as `grails.plugins.springsecurity.apf.filterProcessesUrl` property in config, and by default it's `/j_spring_security_check`.

If you didn't change this value, you can use `/j_spring_security_check` instead of `${postUrl}`.

Spring Securty Plugin have special filter that handles this URL, and authorizes user. Next steps are depends on configuration, but if I remember correctly, by default it redirects user to `/`.

See configuration options at http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/urlProperties.html

Comment: My problem is, that I just want to use this form in the main.gsp and use auth method from login controller to login. How can I tell him to use the auth method of the login controller? I just want to have login on another page, but now on the auth view of the login controller.

Comment: I have changed the ${postUrl} in my form to /j_spring_security_check and it redirects me to that URL after I click on login, but then nothing happens.

Comment: Athentication have to be processed by Spring Security plugin, not login controller. What are you expecting from controller? What should happens after redirect?

Comment: It was my fault. I just didn't understood your answer from above. Sorry. Now it works. :D